# JPA Annotations to forced outer join

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entity, associations

I want to make an association between two entities but I don't know what I do to implicit outer join with JPA annotation.

```
EntityOne 
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    // annotation outer join ???
    private EntityTwo e2;
}
```

Comment: Annotation don't help you for outer join, you can do native query using @Query in repository for outer join

Comment: But I want to fetch the association automatically by Hibernate without using @Query ?

Comment: Then what does outer join means ? How can you map them

Comment: in queries generated i find select ..... cross join ...... So how can changed cross join by left outer join ?